# Timeout exception while waiting for webpage with element in headless chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Following code uses non-headless chrome and it works:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
chrome_options.binary_location = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("C:\User\Program Files\chrome-driver\chromedriver.exe"))

driver.set_window_size(1200, 600) 

driver.get("login-url")
driver.find_element_by_id("loginId").send_keys("uname")
driver.find_element_by_id("newPassword").send_keys("pwd")
driver.find_element_by_name("submit-button").click()
driver.set_window_size(1200, 800)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"user-info")))

v = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[4]/td[5]/span").text

print(v)
```

When I choose to use headless chrome:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("C:\User\Program Files\chrome-driver\chromedriver.exe"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

It throws following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/User/workspaces/pyworkspaces/fin2/venv/process.py", line 28, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"user-info")))
  File "C:\User\workspaces\pyworkspaces\fin2\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

So it seems to fail on following line, in headless chrome:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"user-info")))
```

I also tried `presence_of_element_located`:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"user-info")))
```

But it still gives `TimeOutException`. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the past is adding the argument '--start-maximized':

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
```

Try it hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `presence_of_element_located()` you need to wait for **`visibility_of_element_located()`** and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"user-info")))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#user-info")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='user-info']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I didnt get "As you intent to send a character sequence within the element". I just want to wait till a webpage with element having `id=user-info` loads. Tried replacing `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"user-info")))` with `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='user-info']")))`. Giving same exception.

Comment: @anir You haven't mentioned about your specific usecase on what you intend to do after _...waiting for webpage with that element is obtained..._. Initially I assumed it to be _UserID_ field but now it seems it's _User Info_ field. So changed the code. Let me know the status.

Comment: mistakenly I re-asked same question. Now copied content of that question in this one because that was well written with stack trace. Does your above answer resolves it?